# Plotting Zip codes or postal codes on map with radius coverage

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot zip codes or postal codes (since international) for a specific country. I have a spreadsheet with the city and some postal codes where our stores are. I would like to be able to plot all the zip codes on the map and have a radius coverage of lets say 50 miles around it. How can I do that? I would love to have a dynamic solution where I can apply the settings to multiple countries..

Comment: Do you have php/MySQL on your server? Using these with Ajax is a solution